# Azure Policies via Terraform

Tags: azure, policies

Working on a code to apply CIS policies set via code to track changes.  What I am trying to do is create a custom policy set that contains the policies within CIS Microsoft Azure Foundation Benchmark v1.4.0 initiative definition.  I am using the Terraform’s azurerm_policy_set_definition but repeatedly encounter a listofAllowedLocations issue.

Code:

```
data "azurerm_management_group" "Standard" {
  display_name = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "cis_benchmark" {
  name         = var.cis_policy_name
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  display_name = var.cis_display_name


  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  parameters = local.parameters
  metadata   = local.metadata

 policy_definition_reference {
    policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/e765b5de-1225-4ba3-bd56-1ac6695af988"
    parameter_values     = <<VALUE
    {
      "allowedLocation": {"value": ["eastus"]}
    }
    VALUE
  }
}
```

Error:
Error: creating Policy Set Definition "CIS Benchmark v1.4.0": policy.SetDefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="MissingPolicyParameter" Message="The policy set definition 'CIS Benchmark v1.4.0' is missing the parameter(s) 'listOfAllowedLocations' as defined in the policy definition 'e765b5de-1225-4ba3-bd56-1ac6695af988'."
│
│   with azurerm_policy_set_definition.cis_benchmark,│   on cisbenchmark.tf line 22, in resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "cis_benchmark":
│   22: resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "cis_benchmark" {
│

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the parameter name `allowedLocation`, which should be `listOfAllowedLocations`. Take a close look at the example below, this should solve your issue. I agree it is a bit confusing that the names differ.

```
resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "example" {
  name         = "testPolicySet"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  display_name = "Test Policy Set"

  parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
        "allowedLocations": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The list of allowed locations for resources.",
                "displayName": "Allowed locations",
                "strongType": "location"
            }
        }
    }
PARAMETERS

  policy_definition_reference {
    policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/e765b5de-1225-4ba3-bd56-1ac6695af988"
    parameter_values     = <<VALUE
    {
      "listOfAllowedLocations": {"value": "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"}
    }
    VALUE
  }
}
```

I got this example from the official policy_set_definition [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_set_definition).